# Using PureScript `Pulp repl` with no-js files

Tags: webpack, purescript

On my project we are using CoffeeScript and are now adding PureScript. We load both using webpack and that works fine. But when I want to try things out in `pulp repl`, Pulp only finds the PureScript files. I don't expect it to read the coffeescript files, but it should be able to read the .js files that webpack outputs. How can I get pulp to load the webpack .js files?

To be specific about the error:

```
% pulp repl
PSCi, version 0.12.0
Type :? for help

> import TychosApp.AppState as AppState
> appState = AppState.blank { hackPanel { isShowing = false } }
> appState' = AppState.toggleHackPanel appState
> appState'.hackPanel.isShowing
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './scope'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/winstonw/clients/nitidbit/git/tychos/.psci_modules/node_modules/TychosApp.Interface/foreign.js:4:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

./scope is a coffeescript file that webpack has compiled. Purescript is accessing it via FFI